# Strange drop shadows around UI elements in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome, themes

So recently I've been theming up my Ubuntu install. I started with Arc, and it works well, however after a reboot, the Volume/Brightness popups have strange shadow markings around them. And it goes away when I switch to a different theme, but returns after a reboot. How can I get rid of this?

Here's some pictures of it:

[image]

[image]